# How to replace Microsoft Word text with values from Microsoft Excel while matching style and formatting? Replacing at run level results in no match

Tags: python, automation, docx

Basically, I have a Microsoft Word file that has certain placeholders that I would like to be able to replace with values from a Microsoft Excel file with the same style and formatting as the original document.

Ex:

[Microsoft Word Document] - "The {object} is listed at {price}"

[Microsoft Excel Document] -

| object | price |
| --- | --- |
| watch | $5000 |
| phone | $300 |

[Expected Microsoft Word Document Output] - "The watch is listed at $5000"

I've tried using docx, docx2python, etc. The problem is that using the docx.replace function works but does not match the style of the document and in order to match style, going to run level of docx, the runs are splitting the placeholders apart which leads to no matches on the excel columns.

See below for the code that works best:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/content/sample_data/auto_psa_test.xlsx')
docx_path = '/content/sample_data/template3.docx'
doc = Document(docx_path)

for x in df.columns:
  for p in doc.paragraphs:
    if x in p.text:
      p.text = p.text.replace(x, str([df[x].iloc[0]]))

doc.save('/content/sample_data/output_12.docx')`
```

Ideally, I would like to iterate row by row to create multiple word documents with the contents of each row. Did not think that interacting with Word documents via Python would be so difficult, any help is greatly appreciated!